# Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module I couldn't find the modules

Tags: node.js, babeljs

I'm working with node.js and using the **es6**, **es7** and **es8** features within my project and I'm getting this error: Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module.

even tried using babel but without any success the error persists.

> .babelrc

```
  {
  "presets": ["es2015"]
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: The error is about an import in `src/router/book.js` so you should include at least all the imports in that file, and any that might be `src/controller/book`. Maybe you have `import ... book` where you should have `import ... book.js`?

Comment: Not a lot if info to work with here. How does `src/router/book.js` look like? Where is it being imported? How does your `tsconfig.json` look like?